# Why the vector field I get is not perpendicular to the tangent?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tikz-arrows

I'm wondering why the vector field I get is not perpendicular to the tangent?

[image: What I get]

```
begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},ymin = 0,ymax = 3, domain=-5:5,xticklabels=\empty, yticklabels=\empty]
\addplot3 [blue,-stealth,samples=16, domain=-5:5,
        quiver={
            u={2*x*y},
            v={x^2},
            scale arrows=0.1,
        },
    ] {1}; % use pow(x^2 + y^2,1/2) if you choose to have a real 3D plot
\addplot[purple, thick, domain=-5:5, samples=40]{3/(x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you sooooooo much!!!

Comment: Optical illusion.  Add [axis equal] to the axis options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows the effect of [axis equal].

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}, axis equal,ymin = 0,ymax = 3, domain=-5:5,xticklabels=\empty, yticklabels=\empty]
\addplot3 [blue,-stealth,samples=16, domain=-5:5,
        quiver={
            u={2*x*y},
            v={x^2},
            scale arrows=0.1,
        },
    ] {1}; % use pow(x^2 + y^2,1/2) if you choose to have a real 3D plot
\addplot[purple, thick, domain=-5:5, samples=40]{3/(x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thank you :P

Comment: Indeed, the "stretch" transformation does not preserve angles, nor area.